# How to get the Third party apps for the Teams using graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Please help to get the Third party apps for MS Teams using graph, used

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{TeamsID}/installedApps?$expand=teamsapp,teamsappdefinition](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7BTeamsID%7D/installedApps?$expand=teamsapp,teamsappdefinition) , does not give enough info to distinguish Third-party apps.

Thanks.

Comment: i remember a [related thread discussed about using Powershell](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/report-apps-being-used-in-teams/m-p/1029388). Have a look at it and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Dev Thank you for your response. Even PowerShell does not have any mechanism to differentiate between Third-Party, OOB and Custom apps and PowerShell under the covers call Graph end-points only. Please let me know if you have some other ideas.

Comment: can you elaborate on how you would use that information ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [List Apps in teams Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-list-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0#example-3-get-the-app-installation-resource-based-on-the-manifest-id-of-the-associated-app) by passing the external id (app manifest id). It returns the distribution method in response.

1. Sideloading
2. Store
3. Organization

You can differentiate base on the [distribution Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsapp?view=graph-rest-1.0#teamsappdistributionmethod-values) property.
We have feature in backlog to return full appDefination in response.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but only Custom Apps have External IDs, which does not say anything about Third-party apps. For example: "Evernote" Third Party app does not have any External ID and same for other Out of the Box apps. Distribution method get in response for Installed Apps regardless of using External Id. Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: 3rd party apps do have external IDs , however these are owned by the developer of that application and not shared with you.

Comment: We have feature in backlog to get the full appDefinition in response